# I reinstalled Ubuntu and while downloading Chrome I am getting "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libasound2 (>> 1.0.23):"

Tags: google-chrome, software-installation

Due to this error I am not able to I install Chrome in my system. Please help me!

Output of `apt-cache policy libasound2`

```
libasound2:
Installed: 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7
Candidate: 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7
Version table:
** 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7 0
      500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Now getting one more error from Software Center

> The system package is broken

Comment: Can you post the output of `apt-cache policy libasound2`?

Comment: You should upgrade to Trusty Tahr if you have 1GB or more of RAM. If you are using hardware that is 5+ years old, then try LXLE http://lxle.net/

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel: He says he has Trusty Tahr (in my answer, which I deleted since I assumed he was using Lucid).

Comment: I am using Trusty!!!!

Comment: Strange. Have you tried installing `libasound2` and then installing Chrome?

Comment: how do i install libasound 2

Comment: Ritik had a tag of 10.04 before so that is why we thought he was using Lucid (10.04). If you need this package for Trusty (14.04) then you can follow this http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libasound2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be solved by installing Chrome through repository directly. Just run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

This works for me. You can also install `google-chrome-beta` or `google-chrome-unstable` to get later versions of Chrome.

Comment: Adding repository gives this error "Error: need a single repository as argument"

Comment: Add quotes besides repository.

Comment: Another Error: E: Unable to locate package google-chrome

Comment: Sorry. The correct package is `google-chrome-stable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the package itself. Download the one that fits your architecture from
[here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libasound2). You can check your arch version by

```
uname -a
```

Then you can open the terminal and browse to downloads then install the package.

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

Faced the same problem with Skype before and solved it this way. Cheers!

Comment: how do i browse to downloads in terminal?

Comment: `cd ~/Downloads` or just install it `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/package.deb`

Comment: I am getting another error with that "The system package is broken"

Comment: First try to see if you can update you repos. Run 'sudo apt-get update' also 'sudo apt-get upgrade'. Then try 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'. Try then to install the package again. I am just guessing now because I don't know what is exactly happening. Let me know what you get in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install that missing package with these commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libasound2
```

If this does not work, follow the instructions on [Trusty Package: libasound2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libasound2) to add the source `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, then run the above commands and then try again to install Google Chrome.

Also, be sure to install Google Chrome with the appropriate package (32-bit or 64-bit) found at [Download Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/). It may be helpful to run the install in a terminal instead of the Software Center with this command...

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```